# Why assert throws a reference error

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am exploring Immutablejs documentation, and I found **assert** to be throwing reference error. Here is my code

```
var map = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2});
var map2 = map;
console.log(map);
console.log(map2);
assert(map.equals(map2) === true);
```

And I have included the minified version in the script tag of my page. What might be the error? 
Even `assert(map.equals(map2))` is throwing reference error.

Do they mean to say if `assert` belongs to some testing framework? or is it my problem that I have included in script tag?

Comment: Yes, `assert` is not a standard function. You have to provide the implementation.

Comment: Then why they have provided that extensively in the documentation? 
especially here https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js

Comment: Assertions are a well known concept. It is used there because it makes it clear that the assertion holds. It's the most descriptive and concise way to express  that `map.equals(map2) === true` is indeed `true`. I'd argue that everybody who knows JavaScript also knows that there is no native `assert` function (JavaScript's standard library is tiny).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There assert is a general concept in test driven developments and unit testing.
You should use a assert framework like [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) or write your own framework.

Comment: Cool, I have to check that out. At least they should have mentioned properly  :(

Comment: [This](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html) is an excellent article on using Chai with Immutable.js, Redux, and React